# Objective C - Dynamically compile or do not compile class and codes

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic-programming

First of all; I don't know if this question is duplicate or not. Because I don't know how to search for this question.

Let me explain my question with scenario.

I've iOS 11 Project (Deployment target 9.2). Let's call it Master.

I've coded 2 POD Projects and Master project has reference for them.

```
POD1 has classes A.class B.class and C.class

POD2 has classes D.class E.class and F.class
```

Master project is using both `POD1 and POD2`

Here is the question; What if I want to remove `POD1` reference and want to distribute project with just `POD2`?

I have to remove all codes inside Master which using `POD1`? I don't think so... It is very amateur way to do it. And there should be professional way to do it.

Maybe Run Script?

or

Maybe putting some flags inside code where using `POD1` classes to exclude from build? So I don't get error as File Not Found..

I know the way using

```
#ifndef HIDE_<insert name here>

CODE

#endif
```

But don't think it's a correct way to do it..

Any ideas & suggestions are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking if you can selectively compile, or not compile, a particular module (source file) in a project? In Xcode you would do this by creating a project/workspace with multiple targets. then for each file just tick off which targets that file is included in the file inspector.

Comment: @JamesBucanek Actually no. But close enough. I want to compile or not compile a particular code block in source file. Like what #ifndef HIDE_ block does...

Comment: The only other tool would be to use Objective-C categories. You can isolate your optional functions in a category, put the category code in its own modules and then enable/disable that category's compilation in the project.

Comment: @JamesBucanek Sounds interesting. Are you able to provide sample code ? I know Objective Categories, but never heard about using for this purpose..

Answer (score 1):

Using Objective-C categories, you can conditionally compile groups of methods for different targets. Here's an example.

Let's say you have two targets that both use a class `A`. In one target (a background daemon) you need just the core functionality of class `A`. In the GUI version of your app you need the same functionality *plus* additional methods to support the user interface. The problem is that you can't simply compile all of class `A` in the daemon target because it will reference Cocoa classes that the daemon target doesn't get linked to. You need to isolate the user interface code and compile/link it only in the target that uses it. Here's how:

Base classes

*A.h*

```
@interface A : NSObject
@property NSUInteger someProperty;
- (void)doSomething;
@end
```

*A.m*

```
@implementation A
- (void)doSomething
{
    // Do something useful
}
@end
```

Now define the GUI specific methods in a category:

*A+ViewAdditions.h*

```
@interface A (ViewAdditions)
@property (readonly,nonatomic) NSView* view;
@end
```

*A+ViewAdditions.m*

```
@implementation A (ViewAdditions)
- (NSView*)view
{
    // Create a view that will display this object
    NSView* view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    return view;
}
@end
```

In both targets, you include/compile the `A.m` module, so both targets compile the core class `A` which includes its `someProperty` and `doSomething` method. But in your GUI target, you also compile the `A+ViewAdditions.m` module. In your GUI app, the `A` class has a `view` property, but in your daemon it will not. You can test for this at runtime:

```
A* a = [A new];
if ([a respondsToSelector:@selector(view)])
    NSLog(@"a.view is a %@",a.view.className); // prints "is a NSView"
else
    NSLog(@"a has no view property");
```

This can be extended to subclasses:

*B.h*

```
@interface B : A
@end
```

*B.m*

```
@implementation B
@end
```

*B+ViewAdditions.h*

```
@interface B (ViewAdditions)
@end
```

*B+ViewAdditions.m*

```
@implementation B (ViewAdditions)
- (NSView*)view
{
    NSTextField* fieldView = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    return fieldView;
}
@end
```

And...

```
A* a = [A new];
B* b = [B new];
if ([a respondsToSelector:@selector(view)])
    NSLog(@"a.view is a %@",a.view.className); // prints "is a NSView"
if ([b respondsToSelector:@selector(view)])
    NSLog(@"b.view is a %@",b.view.className); // prints "is a NSTextField"
```

There are limitations to categories, which you should be aware of. The most problematic is that you can't add instance variables or stored properties to a class via a category. But category methods can access private variables in the class, and I'll sometimes define private ivars in the base class that only get used by the category. Your style may vary.